# Twitter Bootstrap: Difference between Grid and Layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap scaffolding documentation (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) describe the Grid system but introduce the Layout concept just after...

If the Grid system is intended for designing page layout, what is the purpose of this Layout concept?

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Layout in the context of Twitter Bootstrap defines the environment for the grid.
Or in other words it defines the outer width of the grid.

You can choose between Fixed and Fluid.

- Fixed means your Grid will have an absolute (max) width (e.g. 960px).
- Fluid means your Grid will fit to the size of the browser window.